# How to calculate a member of a list using other members in R?

Tags: r, list

Given a list:

```
list(a = 5, b = 8)
```

I want to use `a` and `b` to compute `c`:

```
list(a = 5, b = 8, c = a + b)
```

I know I can do this in `dplyr tibbles` but how can I do this in lists?

Here is what I mean:

```
> library(tibble)
> tibble(a = 5, b = 7, c = a + b)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5     7    12
```

Can I do the same with lists?

Comment: `list1 <- list(a=10, b=20) ; list1$c <- list1$a + list1$b` or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva no no, I want to do it on the fly, like we can do it with tibbles

Comment: @arun can you please look at it?

Comment: Does this work for you, `list(a = 5, b = 8, c = eval(substitute( a + b, list(a = 5, b=8))))`, may be not ? or if `k = list(a = 5, b = 8)`,  you can do `c(k, c = eval(substitute(a+b,k)))`

Comment: I'm too ashamed to post this as an answer... but `list(a=a<-5, b=b<-8, c= a+b)` would work..

Comment: Following my last comment, if you don't want to be left with `a` and `b` floating around.. If you didn't want to be left with `a` and `b` floating around.. `do.call(function() list(a=a<-5, b=b<-8, c = a+b),list())`

Comment: @GeorgeSavva can you please explain the notation? Why does it work?
Please explain the a = a <- 5...

Comment: @GeorgeSavva please explain how this "trick" or method called also

Comment: `a=a<-5` creates an object called `a` then uses it as the argument in the function.  So when we come to `c=a+b` the object called `a` already exists.  This is a horrible solution, but I expect there is a better way to achieve your goal than trying to create lists like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
l<-list(a = 5, b = 8)
l$c=l$a+ l$b


# out put:

> l
$a
[1] 5

$b
[1] 8

$c
[1] 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `with` and simple `c`oncatenation.

```
lst1 <- c(lst1, c=with(lst1, a + b))
```

Or using `transform`.

```
lst1 <- as.list(transform(lst1, c=with(lst1, a + b)))
```

### Result

```
lst1
# $a
# [1] 5
# 
# $b
# [1] 8
# 
# $c
# [1] 13
```

---

*data*

```
lst1 <- list(a=5, b=8)
```